# Is it possible to apply joiner (collector, accumulator) over function using Java Guava?

Tags: java, collections, guava, java-stream, joiner

Is it possible to collect Strings over collection while grouping? That's how it works in Java 8:

```
Map<String, String> discountOptions = p.getDiscountOptions().Stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(
        this::getDiscountName,
        Collectors.mapping(this::getValue, Collectors.joining(","))));
```

I'm curious, is there concise way to do it in Google Guava? That's how I try to replicate it in Guava:

```
Map<String, Collection<String>> stringCollectionMap = Multimaps.transformValues(
    Multimaps.index(p.getDiscountOptions(), 
        new Function<DiscountOption, String>() {
            @Override
            public String apply(DiscountOption d) {
                return getDiscountName(d);
            }
        }),
    new Function<DiscountOption, String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(DiscountOption d) {
            return getValue(d);
        }
    }).asMap();

Map<String, String> discountOptions =  Maps.transformValues(
    stringCollectionMap,
    new Function<Collection<String>, String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(Collection<String> strings) {
            return Joiner.on(",").join(strings);
        }
    });
```

Comment: When you say “do it in Google Guava” do you mean “do it without Java 8 language features”? Or why don’t you use lambda expressions/method for these functional interfaces?

Comment: Yes, without Java 8 and my goal is do it in more imperative way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not going to get anything more concise than the Java 8 streams API, since the reason it exists is to improve these kind of operations.

Pre-Java 8 functional programming can be jury-rigged with Guava's functional utilities, but [as they warn](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/FunctionalExplained#caveats):

> As of Java 7, functional programming in Java can only be approximated through awkward and verbose use of anonymous classes.... *Excessive* use of Guava's functional programming idioms can lead to verbose, confusing, unreadable, and inefficient code.... Imperative code should be your *default*, your *first choice* as of Java 7.

Here's an imperative translation of your code:

```
private static final Joiner COMMA_JOINER = Joiner.on(",");

ListMultimap<String, String> groupedByDiscountName = ArrayListMultimap.create();
for (DiscountOption option : p.getDiscountOptions()) {
  groupedByDiscountName.put(getDiscountName(option), getValue(option));
}

ImmutableMap.Builder<String, String> builder = ImmutableMap.builder();
for (Entry<String, Collection<String>> e : groupedByDiscountName.asMap().entrySet()) {
  builder.put(e.getKey(), COMMA_JOINER.join(e.getValues());
}
Map<String, String> discountOptions = builder.build();
```

It's shorter and easier to read. Given your current API this is roughly the best you can do with Java 7.

That said you might consider re-examining your API - in particular it's odd that you'd use static methods (`getDiscountName()`, `getValue()`) to extract data from your `DiscountOption` class - these seem like clear candidates to be instance methods. Similarly you might consider creating a `Discounts` class that contains one or more `DiscountOption` instances and provides a `toString()` that returns your comma separated string. Then you just need to construct your `Discounts` objects and you're good to go.

Comment: "You're not going to get anything more concise than the Java 8 streams API" unless you use something like [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/). Kotlin's bytecode is compatible with Java 6 and newer ([FAQ - Kotlin Programming Language](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/faq.html)).

Comment: @mfulton26 lets not open the discussion to other languages; there are obviously more concise alternatives in more concise languages. The question is about Java and Guava, not arbitrary JVM languages.